My question Was to know how to solve such questions: find all integer solutions for $x^{6} + x^{3}y = y^{3} + 2y^{2}$
how to solve such questions: find all integer solutions for $$x^{6} + x^{3}y = y^{3} + 2y^{2}$$
I couldn't figure out a way to solve it. My idea was to take $x^{3}=k$
and then solve the quadratic and that $b^2−4ac$ should be a perfect square.. But I couldn't proceed after that. Is there any way to address the problem if my original idea doesn't lead to a successful solution? (note: without calculus)

Not sure what you are asking.  In general, high degree Diophantine equations are hard.  There aren't general methods that work across the board.   I suggest writing out your idea for this particular one in greater detail.  Worth noting that there are some small solutions (which at least means that you won't be able to, say, use easy modular techniques to rule out the existence of solutions).

Where does this problem come from? As lulu says, if you write down a random diophantine equation of high degree, it's likely between very hard and unsolvable with our current knowledge. If this comes from some class or textbook, it would be very helpful to know the context.

$(x,y)= (0,0),(0,-2),(2,4)$ are Integer Solutions

I just found it somewhere online. I don't remember where it was though

I mean how did you get the solutions.

Let $y=16k^2+4k-2$ and $x^3=64k^3+16k^2-8k$   or $-64k^3-32k^2+4k+2$

Writing the equation as $x^3(x^3 + y) = y^2(y+2)$, by parity arguments, we can show that $y$ cannot be odd.  If $y \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, again by similar arguments, it will force $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$; setting $x = 0$ gives your first two solutions above.

I wonder if the factorization $y^3=(x^3+2y)(x^3-y)$ could lead to a solution. No luck on my end so far, but it looks too nice to not return anything.

Previously posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/481141/my-question-was-to-know-how-to-solve-such-questions-find-all-integer-solutions

Your idea about the discriminant is a good start, and can be pushed through to a solution (but it does take a bit more work than just a few lines). As you've not shown your thought process, it's not clear to me why you "couldn't proceed after that".
Here is an outline of the solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and why you can't push through.

By considering the discriminant, show that $4y+9 = a^2$ is a perfect square.
With $ a= 2k+1$ we get $ y = (k+2)(k-1)$ and $ x^3 = -(k+2)(k-1)( 1 \mp (2k+1) ) / 2$.
This can be bound between 2 consecutive cubes for large enough $k$, hence solutions only exist for small enough $k$, leading to the 3 that you found.


@Guruprasad See the third point. Highlight text for a hint $\color{white}{-k^3 < -(k+2)(k-1)(1+2k+1)/2 < (k+1)^3}$ for all but finitely many integers.

@Guruprasad Per the hint (highlight the blank white space for it to show up), we have $ k^3 < -x^3 = (k+2)(k-1)(1+2k+1)/2 < (k+1)^3$ for all but finitely many $k$. So we have to test $k = -3, -2, -1, 0, 1$. $\quad$ And do the same for the other branch.

Can you please elaborate on your third statement. thanks

@AdvithReddyKaukuntla Can you please elaborate on what you do not understand about it, and what you've thought about it? Thanks.
